# Session not working in Base Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Problem**

Base Controller is being extended in User Controller. I am trying to check if session is null...if so, it should go to login page. But due to some reasons this is not working.

**Base Controller**

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $user = Session::get('User');

        if ($user == null)
        {
            return Redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

**user Controller**

```
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function AllUsers()
    {
        $Users = \App\Models\User_Model::all();
        return view("/User/List", array("Users" => $Users));
    }
}
```

**Account Controller**

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view("/User/login");
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index');
Route::get('/Users', 'UserController@AllUsers');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way to do it. Use Middleware to have something run before each action.
By default `auth` middleware handles that.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new UserController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

If you want the middleware to run for all your requests, then add it to your Kernel. In your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file, add the below:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,    //add this one only, the rest should be there by default.
];
```

In your `app\Controllers\AuthController.php`, change the default route:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/';
```

**Just a side note, probably running auth to all your requests, will create loops, as the user won't be able to reach even login page or home page.**

Comment: can't I put the code `$this->middleware('auth');` in contructor in base controller ? like it is done in my post. After doing this, I got 404 error.